# jquery .find or .closest then addclass not working in IE or Chrome

Tags: jquery, find, addclass, closest

Works in FireFox.  Does not work in IE8 or Chrome:

```
<script>
$('.PageText_L657n').closest('td').find('.pricecolor').addClass('ice1');
</script>
```

Should be a line-through "Regular Price:$ XX.XX" if "Click To Get Today's Special Price" appears in the table.

[CLICK HERE TO SEE IT IN ACTION ON MY SITE](http://www.basequipment.com/SearchResults.asp?searching=Y&sort=5&search=True&show=100&page=1&cat=2847)

Comment: Well, there is no element with class `PageText_L657n` on that page. I really doubt, that it works in FF, then.

Comment: I dont see class PageText_L657n anywhere in the source

Comment: Show us your css please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your code in [ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('.PageText_L657n').closest('td').find('.pricecolor').addClass('ice1');
});
</script>
```

Since you are manipulating the DOM, you need the ready handler which firs as soon as DOM becomes ready.

Also make sure element with class `PageText_L657n` is there is pointed out by @T.J Crowder.

Comment: ToddN: This will cause your code to wait until the document ready instead of executing immediately.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the source of that page with the `PageText_L657n` class. Also, you're executing that code before there's much of anything in the DOM (either put it at the bottom, just before your closing `body` tag, or use the [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function).

Comment: @ToddN: I don't see it with Firefox, either. And if I open Firebug and let that page fully load, `$(".PageText_L657n").length` returns `0`. So that'll be the first problem. :-) And then, again, you'll need to be sure that you're doing the search *after* the content is already in the DOM, via `ready` or whatever.